# Create index on CASE expression in Derby

Tags: sql, derby

I'
m trying to create an index on CASE expression, as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX symbol_unique_idx ON "USER" (CASE WHEN deleted = 0 THEN symbol ELSE NULL END);
```

and getting error:

```
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "CASE" at line 1, column 54.
SQLState:  42X01
ErrorCode: 30000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby doesn't support that syntax for `CREATE INDEX`.

Here's the Derby documentation for `CREATE INDEX`: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj20937.html

Derby does support "generated columns":http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqljgenerationclause.html

So perhaps you can change your table definition to include a column which is `GENERATED AS (expression)`, with the desired expression to compute your data.

And then you can include that column in your index.

Comment: Thanks. So, is there any different way to do that?

Comment: There are generated columns, which might work for you. I edited the answer.